# Deployed website Error

Tags: iis

I created a website but it was built with the wrong code from TFS. Because of this I copy the correct code web folder from my c: drive to the IIS website folder. The website runs fine; however, when I try to build the site in VS I get the following error:

Error 102 The configSource file 'appSettings.config' is also used in a parent, this is not allowed.

Comment: When I try to add the new code to source control I get the following error:

The following IIS Virtual Directories cannot be added to source control at this time because their files do not reside under the Local Path of the root Web site localhost :  https://localhost (D:\TAMIS-Root\Web)

Click Continue to add all other Web items to source control. Click Cancel to stop adding files to source control.

Comment: My D:\TAMIS-Root\Web is on my localhost.  What I have is my IIS installed on my c: drive and the application installed on the d: drive of the same machine. To get the correct code in the correct mapped virtual directory I removed the IIS virtual directory and the wrong code from the mapped virtual directory and coped the correct code's whole directory virtual directory under the https://localhost mapped to the newly created directory of the same name where the virtual directory in IIS is pointing to. I don't know but I think I have to remap the virtual directory on my localhost.